# How do I get fibit python working when hosted on heroku?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, oauth-2.0, cherrypy

I have pulled this repo and have it working on my local machine: https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit

When the file is run it opens up a URL and gets the user to log into Fitbit using OAuth2 and then you can access their Fitbit data.

My issue is that I want to host this on Heroku and it is not working.

In this file it specifies the local URL "http://127.0.0.1:8080/":https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit/blob/master/gather_keys_oauth2.py

How do I get this to work hosted on Heroku?

I have tried to swap out the url for my Heroku url e.g. "https://example.herokuapp.com/" but I get the following error:

```
2020-10-17T15:49:32.221290+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.10.88.48 - - [17/Oct/2020:15:49:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 104 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
2020-10-17T15:49:38.210539+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
2020-10-17T15:49:38.210921+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Listening for SIGHUP.
2020-10-17T15:49:38.211207+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Listening for SIGUSR1.
2020-10-17T15:49:38.211435+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Bus STARTING
2020-10-17T15:49:38.211812+00:00 app[web.1]: CherryPy Checker:
2020-10-17T15:49:38.211813+00:00 app[web.1]: The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.
2020-10-17T15:49:38.211814+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-17T15:49:38.212297+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
2020-10-17T15:49:38.212774+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221990+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Error in 'start' listener <bound method Server.start of <cherrypy._cpserver.Server object at 0x7fe916ef6990>>
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221992+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221993+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 205, in publish
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221993+00:00 app[web.1]:     output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221994+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 168, in start
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221995+00:00 app[web.1]:     ServerAdapter.start(self)
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221995+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 170, in start
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221995+00:00 app[web.1]:     wait_for_free_port(*self.bind_addr)
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221996+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 432, in wait_for_free_port
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221997+00:00 app[web.1]:     check_port(host, port, timeout=timeout)
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221997+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 381, in check_port
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221997+00:00 app[web.1]:     port = int(port)
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221998+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
2020-10-17T15:49:38.221999+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222259+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Shutting down due to error in start listener:
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222259+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222260+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 243, in start
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222260+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.publish('start')
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222261+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 223, in publish
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222261+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exc
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222261+00:00 app[web.1]: cherrypy.process.wspbus.ChannelFailures: TypeError("int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'")
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222262+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222405+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222606+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('example.herokuapp.com', None)) already shut down
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222768+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
2020-10-17T15:49:38.222936+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'.
2020-10-17T15:49:38.223124+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
2020-10-17T15:49:38.223314+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Bus EXITING
2020-10-17T15:49:38.223462+00:00 app[web.1]: [17/Oct/2020:15:49:38] ENGINE Bus EXITED
2020-10-17T15:49:38.241123+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-17 15:49:38 +0000] [48] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 48
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it extracts the port from `redirect_uri` which is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`.
You could try the Heroku url with port 443 `https://example.herokuapp.com:443`

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I will try that shortly when I’m at my laptop